# Method to compare previous day to current day values

Tags: r

I am looking for a better way to compare a value from a day (day X) to the previous day (day X-1). Here I am using the `airquality` dataset. Suppose I am interested in comparing the wind from one day to the wind from the previous day. Right now I am using `merge()` to bring together two dataframes - one current day dataframe and one from the previous day. I am also just subtracting 1 from the `Day` column to get the `PrevDay` column:

```
airquality$PrevDay=airquality$Day-1

airquality.comp <- merge(
  airquality[,c("Wind","Day")],
  airquality[,c("Temp","PrevDay")], 
  by.x=c("Day"),by.y=c("PrevDay"))
```

My issue here is that I'd need to create another dataframe if I wanted to look back 2 days or if I wanted to switch `Wind` and `Temp` and look at them the other way. This just seems clunky. Can anyone recommend a better way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try diff(airquality$Wind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whar kind of comparison do you need?

For example, to check if the followonf values is greater you could use:

```
library(dplyr)
with(airquality, lag(Wind) < Wind)
```

Or with two lags:

```
with(airquality, lag(Wind, 2) < Wind)
```

Comment: @user3949008 You can do it as well once you noticed it :-)

Comment: I don't have permission to edit on fly. Awaits approval for peer review or something.

Comment: This is very much in line with what I was thinking but I would probably do something more like this: `airquality %>%  mutate(WindLag2=lag(Wind,2))`. Should I edit your answer or create my own?

Answer (score 3):

IMO `data.table` may be harder to get used to compared to `dplyr`, but it will save your tail later when you need robust analysis:

```
setDT(airquality)[, shift(Wind, n=2L, type="lag") < Wind]
```

In base R, you can add an `NA` value and eliminate the last for comparison:

```
with(airquality, c(NA,head(Wind,-1)) < Wind)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate or provide a link to justify the data.table/dplyr comparison? I have become very fond of pipes.

Comment: I used to be fond of pipes.  Now I'm in rehab.

Comment: I imagine you will be fond of working with large datasets with ease. Look at http://www.r-bloggers.com/need-for-processing-speed-data-table/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what questions you are trying to answer, but I would look into Autocorrelation (the correlation of a time series with its own lagged values).  You may want to look into the acf() function to compare the time series to itself since this will help you highlight which lags are significantly correlated.

Or if you want to compare 2 different metrics (such as Wind and Temp), then you may want to try the ccf() function since it allows you to input 2 different vectors and it will compute the cross correlation with lags.  For example:

```
ccf(airquality$Wind,airquality$Temp)
```

Comment: Wow! `ccf()` is a game changer for me. Because it is more directly applicable to this question I am going to accept another answer but this is an amazing tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in autocorrelation or cross-correlation, in particular, then you might also consider something like mutual information, which will work for non-Gaussian data as well. Both the `infotheo` and `entropy` ([more here](http://strimmerlab.org/software/entropy/)) packages for `R` have built-in functions to do so.